Creating a numpy array of dictionary-like objects results in different outcome than creating a numpy array from `dict`s
If a class has __len__, __iter__ and __getitem__ defined (but for simplicity not __array__) then np.array will use the iterator to create an numpy array.
import numpy as np

class ArrayDict:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.data.__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.__len__()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data.__getitem__(key)

data = {
    "x": np.arange(10),
    "y": np.arange(10),
    "z": np.arange(10),
}

ad = ArrayDict(data=data)

print(np.array((ad, ad)))

This code returns:
[['x' 'y' 'z']
 ['x' 'y' 'z']]

But only if all three above mentioned methods are defined, if one of them is missing it will return:
[<__main__.ArrayDict object at 0x7fd096e81580>
 <__main__.ArrayDict object at 0x7fd096e81580>]

The only way that I could find to force a creation of a an array of objects, with having all three methods defined, was
oa = np.zeros((2), dtype=object)
oa[0] = ad
oa[1] = ad
print(oa)

resulting in
[<__main__.ArrayDict object at 0x7fd096e2a820>
 <__main__.ArrayDict object at 0x7fd096e2a820>]

What is weird, is, that it actually works with a simple dict:
data = {
    "x": np.arange(10),
    "y": np.arange(10),
    "z": np.arange(10),
}
print(np.array((data, data)))

results in
[{'x': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'y': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'z': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}
 {'x': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'y': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'z': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}]

Why would np.array behave differently with a dict?
